# Override the tags for a test in ScalaTest

Tags: tags, hook, scalatest

I'd like to apply the DRY principle to my ScalaTest test definitions.  Specifically, I'd like to define an abstract test class that defines a bunch of tests.  All of the tests call some function with parameters indicating the conditions to be tested.  The definition of that function is left to the extending class.  So far, this is doable.

Next, I'd like to tag any test that has ever failed and been fixed as a "regression" test, so I can run just those tests if I am so inclined.

But the tests are initially tagged in the abstract class.  I need to override the tags, or add a tag, in the implementing class.

Is there a clean way of doing this?  The documentation implies that there is, but so far I can't find an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I never did find documentation on how to do it, but there was enough information in the ScalaDocs that I was able to figure it out.  For the benefit of those who might want to do something like this, here is what you need to know:

First, you will want to define your own trait that you can mix-in to get this additional behavior.  It will override the definition of tag(), like so:

```
trait _____ extends SuiteMixin with Informing { this: Suite with Informing =>
  // with Informing, etc. is so that you can call info() 
  // to add comments to tests - not strictly needed for this

  abstract override def tags : Map[String, Set[String]] = {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

The implementation must call `super.tags`, and then add whatever needs to be added to the resulting data structure before returning it.  The keys of the result will be test names, the values will be sets of tag strings.  NOTE: tests that have no tags will not be present, so you will not be able to depend on iterating over that object to find the test that you want to operate on.  You will end up having to call `this.testNames` and iterating over that.

Here is an example of code that I wrote that shows how to pull this off.

```
  abstract override def tags : Map[String, Set[String]] = {
    val original = super.tags
    val matching = <list of what to automatically add tags to>
    if ( matching.isEmpty ) original
    else {
      val tests = this.testNames.toList
      def extend( result: Map[String, Set[String]], test_list: List[String] ) : Map[String, Set[String]] = 
        if ( test_list.isEmpty ) result
        else {
          val matches = ( for ( p <- matching if ( <applicable> ) ) yield true ) contains true
          if ( ! matches ) extend( result, test_list.tail )
          else extend( 
            result.updated( 
              test_list.head,
              result.getOrElse( test_list.head, Set[String]() )
                + "<tag-to-be-added>" ),
            test.tail 
          )
        }
      extend( original, tests )
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps someone besides me.

Comments on how to do this in a more elegant or *scala-esque* manner are welcome and appreciated.